# I'm trying to get Saleor Django installation running

Tags: django, cairo, saleor

I have followed all the instructions from the saleor.io docs however, I got stuck at migrating the db. The problem is that every time I run `python manage.py migrate` I get this error message.

I have python 3.8 installed and both GTK 2 and 3,  MSYS2 but nothing seems to work.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
I have tried everything, and have no clue how to install cairo. Please help

```
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Python is 32 bit you must use the 32 bit versions of those libraries. If your Python is 64 bit you must use the 64 bit versions of those libraries. Mismatching the bitness raises the issue. In case you forgot which Python you installed, ask Python (in the console window):
Also go through this doc http://gisaxs.com/index.php/View.gtk_installation as this doc elaborates the proper way installation for GTK